# NSTextview won't show pop-up menu for Korean text replacements

Tags: macos, cocoa, nstextview

(Disclaimer -- I don't understand Korean, so I have some test examples that don't make sense but demonstrate the issue.)

I have a heavily customized NSTextView/NSTextStorage to provide syntax highlighting and other behaviors in my app.  A Korean user pointed out some difficulties using the macOS text replacement functionality.

1. The pop-up menu to accept/reject text replacements doesn't appear.
2. Text replacements of multi-character strings don't work -- it seems to only allow the last character to trigger a replacement.

To test, I configured the following text replacements on my (US English) mac:

1. `해` (created by typing `go`) is replaced with `GO` (creative, I know...)
2. `새` (`to`) is replaced with `TO`
3. `ㅂㅈ` (`qw`) is replaced with `qw`
4. `햅ㅈ` (`goqw`) with `go qw`
5. I enabled the `2-Set Korean` input source (the "Caps Lock to switch" feature is a life saver) (If it matters, I have Font Size 18, Input format `Hangul (Hanja)`, and Delete by `Gulja`.
6. I am running 10.12.6 on this machine.

Test environments:

1. I downloaded Apple's source for TextEdit, compiled, and used that (so that I could confirm TextEdit was compiled using same SDK as my app)
2. I created a "toy" application that consists of a single window.  In the ViewController's `viewDidLoad`, I use this to replace the contents with a basic NSTextView (without any of my customizations):

   ```
   - (void)viewDidLoad {
       [super viewDidLoad];

       NSView * contentView = [self view];
       NSRect cFrame = [contentView bounds];

       NSView * oldView = [[self.view subviews] firstObject];
       [oldView removeFromSuperview];

       // Create basic NSTextView with mostly default settings
       NSTextView * newView = [[NSTextView alloc] initWithFrame:cFrame];
       [newView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
       [self.view setAutoresizingMask:NSViewHeightSizable | NSViewWidthSizable];
       [newView setVerticallyResizable:YES];
       [newView setHorizontallyResizable:NO];

       // Scrollview for convenience
       NSScrollView * scroller = [[NSScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:cFrame];
       [scroller setAutoresizingMask:NSViewWidthSizable | NSViewWidthSizable];
       [scroller setHasVerticalRuler:YES];
       [scroller setUsesPredominantAxisScrolling:YES];
       [scroller setHorizontalScrollElasticity:NSScrollElasticityNone];

       [scroller setDocumentView:newView];

       [self.view addSubview:scroller];

       // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
       textView = newView;
       [textView setRulerVisible:YES];
   }
   ```

Results:

1. Using TextEdit, all of the replacements display a pop-up menu allowing me to accept/reject the replacement as I type (Korean as well as my own English text replacements).
2. Using the toy application, single character replacements are changed automatically, but no pop-up menu is displayed.
3. The two character replacement is not triggered in the toy app.
4. Typing quickly in the toy app (with a space after) allows all Korean replacements to happen, but still no pop-up.
5. English text replacements, including multi-letter words, show the pop-up menu (e.g. `mmd` -> `MultiMarkdown`).
6. Changing the font for the NSTextView doesn't change behavior (e.g. `Times` is same as `AppleMyungjo`).

Reviewing the TextEdit code, I was unable to find anything relevant to indicate what I am doing wrong.  The fact that pop-ups appear with English replacements but not Korean ones seems odd, especially with an unmodified NSTextView.  Using a programmatic NSTextView should exclude me doing something wrong with the Xcode interface builder setup.  TextEdit uses programmatic NSTextViews, and I couldn't see anything obvious in their setup that differs meaningfully from mine, but obviously there is something going on.

Any solutions?

Thanks!

Comment: When I do the `햅ㅈ` replacement and click, the text changes to `Gㅈ qw`. I tried your code and the pop-up menu works (macOS 10.13.4). I removed the last two statements with `textView`.

Comment: It works on my 10.13.4 beta as well, but the same binary does not work on 10.12.6.  The custom TextEdit *does* work on 10.12.6.  (Same goes whether the binary was created on 10.12.6/Xcode 9.2, or 10.13.4/Xcode 9.3)